# Movement in grid in Unity

Tags: unity

I am a beginner at Unity. I want to make a game like Lightbot, but in 2d (without the z axis movement) with some obstacles. Before making the function system of the Lightbot, I want to make the in-game character move on a grid by the set of key inputs (e.g. WASD) by the player. But I'm stuck here. I searched on Tilemap which makes a grid, but I have no idea how to save the set of input keydowns and move my character on this grid at once. Suppose my character is on the (0, 0) square for example. After the player taps WWDD, then my character should move to the following squares, in the following order:

- (0, 1)
- (0, 2)
- (1, 2)
- (2, 2)

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Presumably you started by [searching "Unity grid movement"](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+grid+movement), and found the variety of text and video tutorials that turns up, right? Have you run into any specific trouble when trying to apply what you learned from this research?

Comment: Does the player have to move immediately when you type a key? Or do you first "register" a set of key strokes and *then* move the character using them as an input?

Comment: Not immediately. As you said, we have to register a set of key strokes, and if we press a specific key (e.g. P) then the character has to move.

Comment: The trouble was, "How to save the set of key strokes"

Comment: How does the system know when to start executing the movement? Does it wait for a 'done moving key', wait a certain amount of time or something else?